# Check internet connection speed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a API when I can check the internet connection speed or bandwidth.

**For example:**

- I can identify the network type from reachability class in iOS like
  2G, 3G, 4G, LTE, WIFI.
- I want the speed/bandwidth of internet that are using in network
  type.

Thanks advance.

Comment: This may help you : https://github.com/rldaulton/connectedness

Comment: I have used this code but its not giving the correct info, The information this code sharing basis of downloading Url form NSUrl Connection. Not getting the correct info.

Comment: @PrabhatPandey what do you mean by saying "correct info"? The only way to get a current bandwidth of TCP is to download or upload a large file. Initially, TCP doesn't know the bandwidth; it tries to send/receive more and more packets until some maximum speed is achieved. If you download a 64kb file, for instance, on WiFi, you'll get max speed something like 64kb, because the file is not large enough. So the lib provided above should give you an adequate estimate of the bandwidth if you download/upload some large file via it.

Comment: @dosi "The correct info" means that I want a API or mechanism who will ensure me that bandwidth regularly in each interval. The approach you are defining is just depend on the basis of send/receive packets. I appreciate you if you can share me a better idea to achieve this, Again thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use SpeedOfMe API